# What is the difference between online, offline, enabled and disabled in Solaris services?

Tags: service, solaris

When svcs -a is entered on the terminal, a list of services with its corresponding status is displayed. May I ask, what does each status mean and what is the difference between the statuses online, offline, enabled and disabled?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an `enabled` state can be reported by `svcs -a`. The [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1474/smf-5.html) states are:

- uninitialized
- offline
- online
- degraded
- maintenance
- disabled
- legacy-run

If the state is followed by `*`, that means it is transitioning.

The difference between `offline` and `disabled` is that in the former case, the service is enabled but doesn't run for some reason. Use `svcs -xv` to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Solaris in particular, but on Linux they map to:

- online: running
- offline: not running
- enabled: automatically starts on boot
- disabled: no autostart

Comment: With Solaris smf, you can temporarily enable a service (`svcadm enable -t service`), so it will be enabled but won't be automatically restarted at reboot.

Answer (score 0):

w00p woop

SunOS 11.3

> Impact: This service is not running.